# Cannot find method getRange(int,int) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I change a `getRange('D4')` command to a `getRange(i,4)` or even `getRange(4,4)` I get the error:

> Cannot find method getRange(number,number)

I am editing a Google Sheets macro function that intends to copy data from a known cell 'G6' to a given row (i) in column D (in this particular instance 'D4') based upon matching an index in column C to determine the row i.

I believe the for-loop correctly identifies the row correctly, but please tell me if there is an obvious issue with this.

```
spreadsheet.getRange(i,4).activate();
```

because it returns the titled error

> Cannot find method getRange(number,number).

I also get this error if I try

```
spreadsheet.getRange(4,4).activate();
```

however, there is no issue when I run

```
spreadsheet.getRange('D4').activate();
```

which is where I began to record a macro.

```
function CopyMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var data = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var playerID = spreadsheet.getRange("F3").getValue();
  var playerID2 = spreadsheet.getRange("F6").getValue();
  spreadsheet.getRange('I3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
      if(data[i][2] == playerID){
        spreadsheet.getRange(i,4).activate();
        spreadsheet.getRange('G6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);        
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this answer?

### Modification points:

`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` returns `Spreadsheet`. `getRange(row, column)` is the method of Class Sheet. When you want to use `getRange` method for `Spreadsheet`, please use `getRange(a1Notation)`. So in your situation, how about modifying as follows?

### Modified script:

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `getRange(a1Notation)` is used.

From:

```
spreadsheet.getRange(4,4).activate();
```

To:

```
spreadsheet.getRange("D4").activate();
```

- In this case, the 1st sheet is used. For example, if you want to use other sheets, please modify `getRange("D4")` to `getRange("Sheet2!D4")`.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `getRange(row, column)` is used.

From:

```
spreadsheet.getRange(4,4).activate();
```

To:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(4,4).activate();
```

- In this case, the active sheet is used. For example, if you want to use other sheets, please modify `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` to `spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)` and `spreadsheet.getSheets()[i]`.

#### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, your bottom script in your question is modified. When above modification points are used for your bottom script, it becomes as follows. Please think of this as just one of several modifications.

From:

```
spreadsheet.getRange(i,4).activate();
```

To:

```
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,4).activate();
```

### References:

- [getRange(row, column) in Class Sheeet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column)
- [getRange(a1Notation) in Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.