# "Range not defined" error using getRange() within a forEach loop

Tags: google-apps-script, foreach, range

I have searched through some similar questions about getRange() errors witin loops and I'm still not sure what is the best solution.

[Iterate over range, append string to each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605213/iterate-over-range-append-string-to-each)
[Cannot find method getRange(int,int) in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913345/cannot-find-method-getrangeint-int-in-google-sheets)

My columns are set up as:
Column 1 checkboxes
Column 2 Event
Column 3 Start
Column 4 End
Column 5 Description
Column 6 Email
Column 7 POC
Column 8 EventID

This script runs through all the rows that are checked to identify if there is a current eventID, and if not, create a new eventID and set its value.

This is where the error is coming from: `EventsData.getRange(row[7]).setValue(newEventID);`.

Would you please give me some guidance on how best to formulate the getRange() to include the looping?

```
function ReplaceOrCreateEvent()
{ 
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarID");
  var EventsData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  var rows = EventsData.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = rows.shift();
  rows.forEach(function(row)
  {
    if(row[0])
    {
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));
      var eventID = row[7];
      
      if(eventID != 0)
      {
        var event = cal.getEventById(eventID);
        event.deleteEvent();
        Logger.log(event);
      }
        var title = row[1];
        var desc = row[4];
        var tstart = row[2];
        var tstop = row[3];
        var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:desc});
        var newEventID = newEvent.getId();
        EventsData.getRange(row[7]).setValue(newEventID);
        Logger.log(newEventID);
    }
  });
}
```

I have tried setting static values for the said getRange() line, which works: `EventsData.getRange(2,8).setValue(newEventID);` but that doesn't get looped.

I have tried using `EventsData.row[7].setValue(newEventID);` and `eventID.setValue(newEventID);`, which do not work.

I appreciate you looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

By this modification, the value of `newEventID` is put into column "H" of the processed row.

```js
function ReplaceOrCreateEvent() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarID");
  var EventsData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  var rows = EventsData.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = rows.shift();
  rows.forEach(function (row, i) { // Modified
    if (row[0]) {
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));
      var eventID = row[7];

      if (eventID != 0) {
        var event = cal.getEventById(eventID);
        event.deleteEvent();
        Logger.log(event);
      }
      var title = row[1];
      var desc = row[4];
      var tstart = row[2];
      var tstop = row[3];
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, { description: desc });
      var newEventID = newEvent.getId();
      EventsData.getRange(i + 2, 8).setValue(newEventID); // Modified
      Logger.log(newEventID);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

As another modification, in the case of the above-modified script, `setValue` is used in a loop. If you want to move it out of the loop to reduce the process cost, how about the following modification?

```js
function ReplaceOrCreateEvent() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarID");
  var EventsData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  var rows = EventsData.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = rows.shift();
  var res = rows.map(function (row, i) { // Modified
    if (row[0]) {
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(row));
      var eventID = row[7];

      if (eventID != 0) {
        var event = cal.getEventById(eventID);
        event.deleteEvent();
        Logger.log(event);
      }
      var title = row[1];
      var desc = row[4];
      var tstart = row[2];
      var tstop = row[3];
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, { description: desc });
      var newEventID = newEvent.getId();
      Logger.log(newEventID);
      return [newEventID] // Modified
    }
    return [row[7]]; // Added
  });
  EventsData.getRange(2, 8, res.length).setValues(res); // Added
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Tanaike. You are certainly one of our most valued community members.

I just tested both modifications and the end results are identical. Aside from processing cost and time, would you say there is no real difference to having setValue() inside a loop or not?

Comment: @Tien Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Aside from processing cost and time, would you say there is no real difference to having setValue() inside a loop or not?`, this is a benchmark. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4